# Bitmap Resize, only crops the image and no resizing

Tags: c#, image, graphics, resize

I have this code to resize a bitmap, but all it does is to crop it instead of resizing, what I am doing wrong?

```
    public static System.Drawing.Bitmap ResizeImage(System.Drawing.Image image, int width, int height)
    {
        //a holder for the result
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width, height);
        // set the resolutions the same to avoid cropping due to resolution differences
        result.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

        //use a graphics object to draw the resized image into the bitmap
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result))
        {
            //set the resize quality modes to high quality
            graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

            //draw the image into the target bitmap
            graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, result.Width, result.Height);
        }

        //return the resulting bitmap
        return result;
    }
```

and I call the function like this

```
bmPhoto = Imaging.ImageProcessing.ResizeImage(bmPhoto, scaledSize.Width, scaledSize.Height);
```

Comment: Just a side note `graphics.Dispose();` is redundant `using` takes care of it.

Comment: Your method works fine for me. Try with `result.SetResolution...` commented.

Comment: what you mean with result.SetResolution... ?

Comment: Try your method removing that line (`result.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);`).

Comment: same result, it crops the image

Comment: Well no idea, as I posted above I've tested your original code and no problems.

Comment: Can be a problem, the method I am calling the function ? see in above

Comment: I called your method `ResizeImage(Image.FromFile(@"d:\test.jpg"), 250, 250).Save(@"d:\out.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);` so I don't see any problems.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that I had a wrong bitmap when saved the file :( problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Keeping Aspect Ratio
Image resizeImg(Image img, int width)
{                              
    double targetHeight = Convert.ToDouble(width) / (img.Width / img.Height);

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, (int)targetHeight);
    Graphics grp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    grp.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    return (Image)bmp;

}


// Without Keeping Aspect Ratio
Image resizeImg(Image img, int width, int height)
{                                   
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
    Graphics grp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    grp.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    return (Image)bmp;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `Rectangle` object to specify the portion of the new image that you want to fill, like so:

```
graphics.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, result.Width, result.Height), 0,  0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, null);
```

As noted the `Rectangle` specifies that the image should be drawn between the top left and bottom right corner, and then you provide the coordinates of the original image that you want to scale into that area (`0,0,image.Width,image.Height`).

Comment: this does not work, it still crops the image. I also passed the original image sizes to this function to be sure that I have the right original sizes and the same result.